# creat stock data from cvs file, list, dictionary

Tags: python, file, list, stocks

My stock programs input is as follow

'Sqin.txt' data read in and is a cvs file

```
AAC,D,20111207,9.83,9.83,9.83,9.83,100
AACC,D,20111207,3.46,3.47,3.4,3.4,13400
AACOW,D,20111207,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,500
AAME,D,20111207,1.99,1.99,1.95,1.99,8600
AAON,D,20111207,21.62,21.9,21.32,21.49,93200
AAPL,D,20111207,389.93,390.94,386.76,389.09,10892800
AATI,D,20111207,5.75,5.75,5.73,5.75,797900
```

The output is

```
 dat1[]
['AAC', ['9.83', '9.83', '9.83', '9.83', '100'], ['9.83', '9.83', '9.83', '9.83', '100']]
```

dat1[0] is the stock symbol 'ACC' used for lookup and data updates
Dat1[1....?] Is the EOD (end of day) data
At the close of stock markets the EOD data will be inserted at dat1.insert (1,M) each update cycle . 
Guys you can code this out in probably one line.  Mine so far is over 30 lines, so seeing my code isn't relevant.  Above is an example of some simple input and the desired output.

If you decide to take on some real world programing please keep it verbose.  Declare your variables, then populate it, and finally use them ex.

```
M = []
M = q [0][3:]  ## had to do it this way because 'ACC' made the variable M [] begin as a string (inmutable).  So I could not add M to the data.-dat1[]- because -dat1[]- also became a string (inmutable strings how stupid). Had to force 'ACC' to be a list so I can create a list of lists -dat1-

Dat1.insert(1.M)  ## -M- is used to add another list to the master.dat record
```

Maybe it would be OK to be some what pythonic and a little less verbose.

Comment: Is this homework? Is it a Python course, and if so, does your professor really think you can declare variables in python?

Comment: Tried m = q[0] ## that's 'ACC"  m turned into a string as I said "INMUTABLE" so if I start out with a string how do I add more data to my database when m initiates it as a string.  So adding dat1.insert(1,m) will throw an exception with INMUTABLES.  If this was about school my question would be something as List2[1,1,1,1,1,1,1], List2[2,2,2,2,2} with an output of List {1.1.2.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.1.2.2.2.2} or some "REAL" world application that most in here find relevant.  I have only found one other example, out of many, that you might say is a real world problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary with the names as keys:

```
import csv
import collections

filename = 'csv.txt'

with open(filename) as file_:
    reader = csv.reader(file_)
    data = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in reader:
        # line[1] contains "D" and line[2] is the date
        key, value = line[0], line[3:]
        data[key].append(value)
```

To add data you do `data[name].insert(0, new_data)`. Where name could be `AAC` and value is a list of the data. This places the new data at the beginning of the list like you said in your post.

I would recommend `append` instead of `insert`, it is faster. If you really want the data added to the begin of the list use `collections.deque` instead of `list`.

Comment: Thanks rob Ideally would like to us a header for database with [name.stk1,stk2,stk3........stk?] And this would be used as the dictionary keys. Database keys not important for searching file or updating.  What is necessary is that the program can access each days entries.  The entries will be used in various formulas for processing.  All processing is sequentially through the list until EOF is reached.  What is important is that stk1[3] > stk5[3] or some formula then, write (reportx) .

Comment: My code does exactly what your question requested. If you want to search for date I would have a dict of dicts where the first key is the name and the second key is the date. But you should really be more clear, right now it's just some rambling about supposed "real world" programming.